# Pass a C Structure from Python 3 using Ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c

everyone. I am trying to call a function in a C library that uses a structure as a parameter. In C code (from file *.hh) the structure is look like:

```
typedef struct {
    public:
        long        nPeaks;
        long        nHot;
        float       peakResolution;         
        float       peakResolutionA;        
        float       peakDensity;             
        float       peakNpix;               
        float       peakTotal;              
        int     memoryAllocated;
        long        nPeaks_max;

        float       *peak_maxintensity;     
        float       *peak_totalintensity;   
        float       *peak_sigma;            
        float       *peak_snr;              
        float       *peak_npix;             
        float       *peak_com_x;            
        float       *peak_com_y;            
        long        *peak_com_index;        
        float       *peak_com_x_assembled;  
        float       *peak_com_y_assembled;  
        float       *peak_com_r_assembled;  
        float       *peak_com_q;            
        float       *peak_com_res;         
    } tPeakList;
```

I have created the Ctypes representation of the structure:

```
class PeakFinderStructure(ct.Structure):
    _fields_=[('nPeaks',ct.c_long), ('nHot',ct.c_long), ('peakResolution',ct.c_float), ('peakResolutionA',ct.c_float), ('peakDensity',ct.c_float), ('peakNpix',ct.c_float), 
                ('peakTotal',ct.c_float), ('memoryAllocated',ct.c_int), ('nPeaks_max',ct.c_long), ('peak_maxintensity',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_totalintensity',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), 
                ('peak_sigma',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_snr',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_npix',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_com_x',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_com_y',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_com_index',ct.POINTER(ct.c_long)), 
                ('peak_com_x_assembled',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_com_y_assembled',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_com_r_assembled',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_com_q',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)), ('peak_com_res',ct.POINTER(ct.c_float))]
```

This structure create in function that used in *.cpp. The main problem I face I don't know how to avoid the situation that I put into the call function the pointer of structure the length I can't know before, so the challenge is how to make the implemantation of this fucntion in python 3. I write some code to the point where I don't know what to do after:

```
def _np_ptr(np_array):
    return ct.c_void_p(np_array.ctypes.data)

def peakfinder(peaklist, data, mask, pix_r,
                    asic_nx, asic_ny, nasics_x, nasics_y,
                    ADCthresh, hitfinderMinSNR,
                    hitfinderMinPixCount, hitfinderMaxPixCount,
                    hitfinderLocalBGRadius, outliersMask):
    '''
    C-call : int peakfinder8(tPeakList *peaklist, float *data, char *mask, float *pix_r,
                    long asic_nx, long asic_ny, long nasics_x, long nasics_y,
                    float ADCthresh, float hitfinderMinSNR,
                    long hitfinderMinPixCount, long hitfinderMaxPixCount,
                    long hitfinderLocalBGRadius, char* outliersMask)
    '''
    req = PeakFinderStructure()
    lib = ct.CDLL('')
    pfun = lib.peakfinder8
    pfun.restype = ct.c_int
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
    pix_r = np.array(pix_r,dtype=np.float32)
    len_outliersMask = len(data)

    pfun.argtypes = (ct.POINTER(PeakFinderStructure),ct.c_void_p,ct.c_char_p,ct.c_void_p,ct.c_long,ct.c_long,ct.c_long,ct.c_long,ct.c_float,ct.c_float,ct.c_long,ct.c_long,ct.c_long,ct.c_char_p)
    k = pfun(ct.byref(req),_np_ptr(data),_np_ptr(mask),_np_ptr(pix_r),asic_nx, asic_ny, nasics_x, nasics_y,
                    ADCthresh, hitfinderMinSNR,
                    hitfinderMinPixCount, hitfinderMaxPixCount,
                    hitfinderLocalBGRadius, _np_ptr(outliersMask))
    return k, outliersMask
```

So the question is how to put the pointer of structer in arguments of call function, that will return only in C function.